# Setar texto se checkbox selecionado android

Tags: android, checkbox

Eu tenho o seguinte checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/papel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Papel" />
```

caso ele esteja selecionado é para escrever papel, no info windows do marcador, só que ele está escrevendo "null"

```
    checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        if (cbpapel.isChecked())
          tv.setText("Papel");

        if(!cbpapel.isChecked())
          tv.setText("");
      }
    };
LatLng posicao = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
customAddMarker(posicao, "TESTE", tv);
```

Aguardando sugestões, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar o listener: **setOnCheckedChangeListener**

```
new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        Log.i("valor","papel");
                    }else{
                        Log.i("valor", ""+isChecked);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Não cheguei a testar, mas consegui de uma outra maneira aqui declarando uma variável como string, caso o cbpapel estivesse selecionada essa variável seria = a papel, sei que não é a maneira correta, mas até o momento está funcionando